# Problem with package `moderncvheadiii' and package `moderncvbodyiii'

Tags: moderncv, overleaf

I used a [modercv template](https://www.overleaf.com/3792996qqrrwx#/10892178/)  on overleaf. Yesterday, it worked pretty well. However I face a problem today. It is a warning:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncvheadiii.sty:
LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `moderncvheadiii',
               but the package provides `moderncvheadiii'.
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncvbodyiii.sty:
LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `moderncvbodyiii',
               but the package provides `moderncvbodyiii'.
```

Then a new blank line (the red circle part) comes out between address and phone, while it did not exist before.

[image]

I do not know why... overleaf is a online edit environment, I did not changed anything of the original template. How could it appear a warning suddenly? I hope anyone could help me.

here is the related code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{import}

\name{My}{Name}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{my address, line 1, line 2, line 3, postcode}{}{}
\phone[mobile]{+44 12345 12345} 
\phone[fixed]{01234 123456} 
\email{myname@hotmail.co.uk}     
\homepage{www.myname.webs.com}
```